# Why SimpleXML doesn't recognise fields with

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm parsing XML with Simple XML, but there is name that it doesn't looks to understand, for instance

XML

```
<item>
         <art_id>34759</art_id>
         <kind>Car</kind>
         <tics.item.dimension>215/55 R 16</tics.item.dimension>
      </item>
```

SIMPLE XML COMMAND

```
echo $item->art_id; // works
echo $item->tics.item.dimension; // does not work, it shows "itemdimension" but there is value so it should show the value
```

DO I have to do something in order to explain to simpexml that . is into the namespace of the XML? I think this is the issue...

Thanks in advance

Comment: why you haven't accepted my answer. readers will doubt it is correct :))

Comment: yes I could'nt yesterday because it was to early for stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: no problem :) i remembered while was asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
$item->{'tics.item.dimension'}
```

I'm late for your editing :)

Comment: perfect :-) thanks dude ! no problem for the edit, I indeed unrderstood your solution :-)

Comment: PHP does not allow `.` in variable names, this is the concatenation operator. You have do use dynamic variables names - the syntax in the answer.

Comment: @ThW take a closer look, especially for quotes

Comment: The comment is the explanation for your answer. You're using dynamic variables names. Here is a more complete example for the syntax: https://eval.in/374093

Comment: @ThW Thank for your comment. I did not know that undefined T_STRING is equal itself.  So, `echo something;`  results in `something`. Do you know whether this means that you can use one-word string unquoted? Or it does not quite match the syntax and may not work in next versions?

Comment: That's not what's happening here. Yes, undefined string constants have a fallback. But it produces a notice and is sloppy programming. You should not rely on it. Like you can see in my example `$object->{$nameVariable}` and `$object->{'nameString'}` both work. The name string is still quoted and it should be.

Comment: *That's not what's happening here.* - i understand it. *You should not rely on it.* - it is answer for me :) . Thanks